# Andoid Studio - error message in simple hello world program - MainActivity

Tags: android-studio

I don't understand the error message, please help.

[image: Android Studio error message]

Comment: first of all, please post in english. Second: Your android SDK is not correctly installed. You have not accepted the license ...

Comment: sorry for my lenguage mistake

Comment: I opened the SDK Manager yet and that say that i have installed Android Nougat

Comment: You have Nougat = android 7 = API 24. You are trying to build for API 29 = android 10. Therefore you must either change the target SDK of your app to 24 ( but you won't be able to add it to the play store then) or you must install SDK version 29

Comment: where i can see, that i want to program the app for andoid 10?

Comment: I already have apk 30 available. Should I then install that or apk 29?

Comment: In the error message *"platform 'android-29'"* not found. You have to install exactly that sdk you are building for. Have a look in your build.gradle what your `targetSDK` is and install that version or change your targetSDK to a version that you have installed. Or install version 30 and change targetSDK to 30

Answer (score 2):

You need to install an sdk. Open the android sdk manager (Tools...menu, i think) and accept the license to install it.

Comment: das menü habe ich gefunden aber was muss ich dort klicken

Comment: I opened the SDK Manager yet and that say that i have installed Android Nougat